# Memory consumption by two dimensional array of strings and msflexgrid

Tags: string, memory, vb6, msflexgrid

Two dimensional array of string takes 2 times more memory than msflexgrid with same text, how?
Is there any other efficient method in vb6 to save string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All windows in VB are ANSI (8 bit). VB is Unicode (16 bit) internally.

You can save your strings as a byte array. Byte arrays can contain ANSI or Unicode.

Comment: Actually a String can also be used to hold ANSI data with no problem at all.  There is no more effort involved than when managing the same thing contained in Byte arrays.  Caution though, reverting to ANSI for persisted data can lead to nasty Locale Hell bugs for any codepoints beyond the 0 to 127 (7-bit ASCII) range no matter how you store it.